# Post chatter question from apex

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

Is it possible to post a Chatter Question from apex to Group chatter Questions?

I can't find any examples or information about this, There is topic about Editing Questions in API but noting about posting new questions from apex.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you shouldn't be able to (I have not personally tried)

Some things to consider,

- FeedItem posted to a community are normally of Type QuestionPost
- They Usually have a NetworkScope (NetworkId if bellongs to a specific community otherwise AllNetworks)

Additionally, you might want to check what other fields are important for your specific use case.

[FeedItem - SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)